# how to parse csv file of float numbers using d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I want to draw scatter plot using d3. When i run that code it gives an error. my csv data file contains natural as well as float numbers.

here is the code.

```
 <script>
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

            var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 500]);
            var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 500]);


            function render(data){

            xScale.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.Droplet_no; }));
            yScale.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.Amplitude; }));

            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
            circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
            circles
                   .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d.Droplet_no);})
                   .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d.Amplitude);});

                   circles.exit().remove();

                }
                function type(d){
                d.Droplet_no = +d.Droplet_no;
                d.Amplitude = +d.Amplitude;
                return d;}

                d3.csv("test.csv", type, render);
    </script>
```

error is :  attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".

Comment: Can you show us a part of your csv? I want to see those float numbers.

Comment: Droplet_no, Amplitude
2,1075.16089
3,1089.69409
4,1103.73792
5,1113.207
6,1114.81567
7,1114.41553
8,1122.64832
9,1122.99658
10,1123.91357
11,1135.52319
12,1137.12891
My dataest is of this type

Comment: Hmmm, I see nothing wrong in the numbers.

Comment: can i mail you my test dataset. so u can check it.

Comment: No worries, I think I discovered the problem: remove the space just before "Amplitude", in the very first line of your csv. And, if there is any space after the commas in the values for "amplitude", remove all them as well.

Comment: ohh....thanks alot ..what a silly mistake i m doing.